# How to dynamically set meta title, description, and image in a Vue.js application using Vue Unhead and Vue Meta?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-meta, unheadvue

I am working on a Vue.js project where I need to set the meta title, description, and image dynamically based on the data I receive from an API. I'm using Vue [Vue Unhead](https://unhead.unjs.io/setup/vue/installation) and [Vue Meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/) to handle the meta tags. Here's the relevant code in my project:

In main.js:

```
import "./assets/main.css";

import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import "./plugins";
// import { createMetaManager } from "vue-meta";
import { createHead } from '@unhead/vue'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(store);
// app.use(createMetaManager()); // Use Vue Meta plugin
const head = createHead()
app.use(head)
app.mount("#app");
```

On the detail page `onMounted` function, I am calling a function which will call the API and fetch the data using `axios`

```
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";

onMounted(() => {
  fetchOperatorDetail();
});

function fetchOperatorDetail() {
  axios.get(
    `api/route`,
    {
      headers: {
        'time_zone': timeZone,
      }
    }
  ).then((response) => {
    if (Object.keys(response.data.data).length > 0) {
      // Extract data from the API response
      // How can I set this data to the meta title, description, and image dynamically?
    }
  });
}
```

> **The ultimate goal is when I share the URL of the detail page to any platform it should display the meta title, and description along with
> the image.**

I have tried setting static text for the meta title, but I'm struggling to dynamically update the description and image based on the API response. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this using Vue Unhead and Vue Meta or suggest an alternative approach?

Additional context:

1. I've already tried using Vue Unhead and Vue Meta for setting the
   meta tags.
2. The project is built with Vue.js version 3.

**UPDATE**
My Index.js looks like this

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import ListView from "../components/views/ListView.vue";
import { nextTick } from "vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: ListView,
     // meta: { title: "ListView" },
    },
    {
      path: "/:detailpage/:packageid?",
      name: "detailpage",
      component: () => import("../components/views/detail page.vue"),
      //meta: { title: "detail page" },
    },
  ],
});

// const DEFAULT_TITLE = "detailpage";

// router.afterEach((to, from) => {
//   nextTick(() => {
//     document.title = to.meta.title || DEFAULT_TITLE;
//   });
// });

export default router;
```

Comment: _"I'm using Vue Vue Unhead and Vue Meta to handle the meta tags."_ - those are trying to set the meta tags on the client side, I presume? That will not work, at least not for Facebook - their scraper does not execute any JavaScript. The initial HTML your server returns when the URL gets requested, must already contain the meta tags with the correct values.

Comment: Do you mean it isn't possible to set the meta tags on dynamic API call responses?

Comment: You can't set them on the client side, Facebook will ignore any such attempt, because it does not execute any client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use `useHead` in `Vue Unhead`

```js
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { useHead } from '@unhead/vue'

const title = ref('')
useHead({
  title,
})

onMounted(() => {
  fetchOperatorDetail();
});

function fetchOperatorDetail() {
  axios.get(
    `api/route`,
    {
      headers: {
        'time_zone': timeZone,
      }
    }
  ).then((response) => {
    if (Object.keys(response.data.data).length > 0) {
      // Extract data from the API response
      title.value = response.data.data.title || ''
    }
  });
}
```

Here is [docs](https://unhead.unjs.io/setup/vue/how-it-works)

Comment: No luck! @int-qy I tried the same way but the title value does not show up on the browser's tab nor in the view source code. Even I set the static title like a title.value = "DEFAULT"; it does not show  the DEFAULT.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works. I just tried it in my local project. Has any error messages in console?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/gKslvxx2nFE9 No there is no error in the console.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding the Index.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to use functions instead of fixed values to get reactive title and meta description working.

```
import { useHead } from '@unhead/vue';

const titleFromApi = ref('');
const descriptionFromApi = ref('');

useHead({
  title: () => titleFromApi.value,
  meta: () => [
    { name: 'description', content: descriptionFromApi.value }
  ]
});
```

Comment: I get this to work to change the title via the onMounted. But if I make after a setTimeout or promise it wont work

Comment: Ok i fixed it myself. I imported unhead and not @unhead/vue. I did not restart my IDE after changing to @unhead/vue and this was the problem :)